# Most effective way to compile lots of information from different websites

Tags: python

My problem is at work I have to click on a link to a website, then copy the company name, company telephone number and company address to an excel spreadsheet, each one in a different column. This information is in the same place on every website and is just time consuming as I have to click each link and then copy and paste the information across.

I have knowledge of the Python programming language, I just wondered if the best way to go about this is using that language to search through the source of the website and be only left with the relevant information or if to use another programming language. Also, any suggestions on libraries to read up on for guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in combination with requests/urllib to scrape and parse the source code of the website.

Then you can use [Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) to write the data into an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into that now! :D

Comment: If you need any help with it feel free to reply here and i'll get back to you asap!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! I'm going to have a go over the next couple of days, I'm sure you'll hear from me :)

Comment: @tompitts okay! If I was of help so far feel free to mark this as the answer as it really helps me out :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Beautiful Soup Python library for this type of work before. It organizes all the HTML code in a way that you can extract whatever data you want from it easily. You can see an example here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Can't seem to reach that link :/ Are you sure its right?

Comment: I just clicked on it again and I am able to see it. You can also search for "Beautiful Soup Documentation"